# Fedora 30 - VPN L2TP IPSEC disconnects short after connection successfully

Tags: fedora, vpn, strongswan

I am having some problems when configuring VPN in my envrionment.

For Mac and Windows users works normally but for me it connects and disconnects shortly after.

The Router alghoritm:
[image]

My IPSEC configuration:

[image]

Log of successfully connection:

> `mag 07 12:33:17 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1103]: CHILD_SA c0ef92f1-a9ea-4fc7-836d-d39dd8d89395{1} established with SPIs c84f04f6_i 68c438a8_o and TS 192.168.1.228/32[udp/l2tp] === 82.48.127.225/32[udp/l2tp]
>   mag 07 12:33:17 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1103]: connection 'c0ef92f1-a9ea-4fc7-836d-d39dd8d89395' established successfully
>   mag 07 12:33:17 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1103]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
>   mag 07 12:33:17 localhost.localdomain charon[9939]: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down`

Full log: https://pastebin.com/XzW3LJFW

When I connect looks like the peer disconnects me without an error

I am using strongswan